# How does JDBC manage data integrity

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've been asked this question by someone and exploring the answers.

How does the JDBC driver ensure data integrity while transferring the data between Java and database. Anybody has link or any documentation saying how JDBC driver achieves it?

Comment: To ensure the integrity of the transmitted data are you thinking along the lines of JDBC over SSL ?... https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc,-tlsv12,-jks-or-oracle-wallets

Comment: What do you mean with integrity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The driver doesn't "manage" or "ensure" data integrity at all.

That's completely in the responsibility of the database server.

It if was the driver, then all the constraints could easily be bypassed by using a different technology to connect to the database.

Plus: the driver is a **client side** technology and it's impossible to ensure data integrity from only the client side.